# Performance of WCF Web Service Call

Tags: c#, .net, performance, profiling, s#arp-architecture

I have a windows application that calls into a WCF web service.  On the server side I am using S#arp Architecture as a base framework.

When making calls to the server the application isn't as responsive as it should be with calls to the server taking in the region of a couple of seconds.

I profiled the application with Ants Profiler and noticed that it was the service call that was the problem. Particularly the method shown below.

```
Namespace                                      Time with Children

SharpArch.Data.NHibernate
.RepositoryWithTypedId<T, IdT>.Get(IdT id)    1.326
(JIT Overhead)                                 1.261
```

I cannot get any more information from profiling the application and I don't understand why JIT would be so high. Response times would be acceptable if I could clear this up.

Any help would really be appreciated.

Comment: Just a suggestion, get S#arp sources, compile, and trace/debug inside .Get().

Answer (score 2):

Maybe its nhibernate loading up?

You can try a new version of s#arp, with [nhibernate configuration caching](http://groups.google.com/group/sharp-architecture/browse_thread/thread/284f529fa5c5a875)